# Why does rotation happens about hinge point in a vertical bar when net force acting on it are zero?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, free-body-diagram, statics, moment

[image: couple is acting here in the rod .]
As we know that if the net external force on a body is zero its center of mass will be at rest and also rotation will happen about center of mass only but in this hinge and rod case it is clear by intution that rotation happens about hinge only(but then center of mass will have linear acceleration which should not happen) .I need explanation to it as i am not able to do it .I think may be its constrained due to that something is happening .please someone clear my doubt.

Comment: Are the "P" elements forces?  What about the hinge?  Is that supplying a force?  Is that part of your sum?

Comment: No it will not apply force in this case

Comment: So if the hinge were not present, the top of the rod would remain in the same place, correct?

Comment: No it would have linear acceleration

Comment: Then the hinge must be preventing that motion.  The only way it can prevent that motion is by applying a force.  You have not accounted for that force.

Comment: But again the translational equilibrium will be disturbed if we draw free body diagram .Its confusing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.  There are three forces applied to this bar.  two from the marked "P", and one from the hinge.  The bar is not in translational equilibrium.  That's why it starts moving.

Comment: How can the hing allow the rod to be translational equilibruim it allows only rotation

Comment: The hinge prevents the end of the rod from moving.  But the forces it applies to do that may in fact be responsible for moving the center of mass.

Comment: @HIMANSHUKUMAR Be careful when you say "rotation." Rotation always occurs around some point. And in this case, the rotation is happening around the hinge, so the whole bar -- CoM included -- are rotating around the hinge. And if you consider the CoM, then it is clearly translating.

Comment: But in translation i have studied all points of the body travel same distance but here all points are in circular motion.Could you please explain i think my concepts are weak.

Comment: @user256872 please answer

Answer (score 1):

Because the net force is not zero. The hinge will exert a force on the body, and this force is what accelerates the center of mass.

Comment: Why will the hinge apply force unneccessarily when it is in equilibrium

Comment: @HIMANSHUKUMAR The hinge is already applying a force (it's why the rod doesn't fall to the ground). The constraint of the problem is that the body can only rotate about the hinge. If the hinge exerted no force on the rod, then the top rod would move away. Some force needs to keep the top of the rod in place. That force is provided by the hinge.

Comment: Yes but in only vertical direction to balance its weight but why in horizontal

Comment: @HIMANSHUKUMAR if there was no horizontal force provided by the hinge, then the top part of the rod would move. But the constraint is that the top part remains attached to the hinge. In order to remain attached, the hinge must exert a force on the top part of the rod.

Comment: But,then the translational equilbrium wouldn't be disturbed if we draw the free body diagram of rod.

Comment: @HIMANSHUKUMAR if the CoM moves then there is no translational equilibrium, yes.

Comment: But in translation i have studied all points of the body travel same distance  but here all points are in circular motion.Could you please explain i think my concepts are weak.